# Preventing multiple connections to server

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have a flash client that connects to a linux server over a TCP socket. Users login with account name / password but some users are making multiple accounts and logging in on these multiple accounts at the same time.

**What can I do to prevent multiple logins from the same computer?**

I don't think I can do anything with IP since people sharing the same internet at a school, household, etc would not be able to login.Since it's a flash client I don't think I can do anything client side. What are my options here? Maybe something with a MAC address?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: I read on another forum that using a combination of MAC address and IP address could be a good solution. Any comments?

Comment: Sounds more like you should solve the problem instead of the symptom. Ask yourself this: why do you consider such multiple connections "evil", if you yourself state that they are ok for various situations? There might be multiple users working on the same machine, that would be a legal usage which you would want to support. Not all systems are limited to single user modes...

Comment: It's a multiplayer game. Multiple users on the same computer isn't possible, one of them would have to be afk. It also allows for multiple accounts in the same game to cheat. I wouldn't be here asking if it wasn't a problem :)

Comment: Why aren't multiple separate players on the same system possible? I do agree that this is not a typical scenario, but impossible? Anyways, why does this pose a problem at all? That was my question. There is no reliable way to prevent this anyway. MAC addresses can be set manually and the routing is software controlled as well. A single system can have multiple separate ip addresses (and often does). So what is the point in trying to nail down that?

Comment: Okay maybe it isn't possible to prevent completely, but at least making it harder than "open up another browser tab and log in with a different account" is preferred. I'm guessing 95% of users wont know how to change their MAC address and IP address, and having to do so between each separate login becomes a big pain in the ass for the people that do know how to do it.

Comment: Which does not answer the question why you want to prevent separate accounts to login in the first place. To me that sounds like a conflict to the whole idea of a multi user game. But as you wish :-)